# Разделить число JavaScript

Tags: javascript

У меня есть переменная x которое равна 5,
var x = 5;

Я хочу получить такой результат // 1,2,3,4,5

Как это реолизовать?

Comment: а что значит результат? Массив? Вывод в консоль? Выполнение 5 раз?

Comment: Создать массив,записать 5, потом отнять 1 и записать результат в следующую ячейку, и так до 0.. Считывайте элементы массива от последнего индекса к первому и записывайте в строку разделяя их запятыми.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете воспользоваться перебором, используя число в переменной, как длину.

```js
    var x = 5; //Ваша переменная
    var result = []; // Массив, в который будем добавлять элементы
    for (let i=1;i<=x;i++){ // Перебор начиная с 1 и до указанного числа
        result.push(i); // Добавляем в массив (Можно заменить на добавление в строку.
    }
    console.log(result); // Выводим результат в консоль, или просто можно использовать result.
```

Comment: А как сделать когда число дошло до 3 сработало <br>?

Comment: @Суро Закарян Что Вы имеете ввиду? Вам надо их вывести в строку, по очереди, или каким-то ещё образом?

Comment: Я result напечатал на экран с помощью document.write(); хотел узнать как сделать если у меня 6 чисел, 1,2,3,4,5,6 а каждая втарое число переводилось на новую строку вот так 1,2 и тут сработал <br> затем 3,4 <br> и так далее

Comment: Все я уже сделал спасибо вам большое